# Неправильно отсчитывается "время последнего посещения" в профиле

Tags: дефект

Если я захожу в свой профиль (не на мете, а на сайте по программированию на русском), то там есть поле "время последнего посещения". Так вот, иногда в этом поле правильная цифра, а иногда я сижу полчаса на сайте, а в этом поле указана 1 минута или 1 секунда или еще какая-то явно заниженная величина.

Comment: «я сижу полчаса на сайте ...» может имелось ввиду «я не сижу»? Если Вы сидите на сайте, то это самое сидение и считается посещением.

Comment: @default locale Имеется ввиду, что я вошел на сайт и полчаса читаю вопросы. Потом я захожу к себе в профиль, а там написано, что время последнего посещения 1 минута.

Comment: Посещение страницы профиля тоже считается :) Это метрика скорее для других чем для Вас.

Comment: @default locale Ничего не понял. Посещение профиля обнуляет счетчик последнего посещения? Но иногда я сижу на сайте полчаса и когда захожу в профиль, то там совершенно правильно написано, что что время последнего посещения полчаса.

Comment: Ну да, счетчик тупой и заметно лагает. У меня сейчас написано «10 минут назад».

Comment: @default locale [счетчик тупой и заметно лагает] Вот я и обращаю внимание администрации на этот дефект. Счетчик считает как-то странно.

Comment: Да, я просто обратил внимание на то, что счетчик ошибается в другую сторону (показывает больше чем нужно). Что касается администрации, то она [показывает на кэш](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108661/a-user-seen-12mins-ago-but-posted-a-question-9-mins-ago-how?rq=1) и ничего по этому поводу делать не собирается